# Make search button search a folder in my database?

Tags: php

How can i make my search button search a folder in my database and echo the file/image?
I have a search form with the `action="search.php?go"`

I have tried this code:

`$dir = "/site/wwwroot/testfolder";


if (is_dir($dir)){
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
            echo "<img src=" . $file . "/>";

        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
    }`

It does not read out the files in the folder. I have image files in the folder and trying to make it echo the image. Could someone lead me in the correct direction? Thank you!

Comment: try echo `'<img src="$file"/>';`

Comment: And then there is a whole lot more you will need to learn

Comment: Learn programming basics please :-)

Comment: With the current problem in mind what should i mainly focus on?